# Spring Properties File

Tags: spring, properties

I am using this in my application config to specify where to get my messages

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="WEB-INF/properties/messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

How do i declare a bean same like this which can be accessible to my java class codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one, instead of creating your own, via:

```
@Resource(name="messageSource")
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Comment: Where does this look for the messageSource file? My project folder has folders for each subsytem. Each subsytem has its own properties file in its own folder. Or can I set where or what folder it makes the lookup for the file?

Comment: wherever you tell it to look. You can define as much message sources as you need, and inject them, lthough I wouldn't recommend this if they are to many.

Comment: What do you mean by injecting them? where do I sepcify where it will look up?

Comment: Do I write something like this?    

       @Resource(name="com.package.resource.messages") 
       private MessageSource mesgSource;

Comment: no. You define your messageSource beans in your applicationContext.xml and then inject (you should be familiar with this term) them wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of the messageSource bean is correct as long as your messages are in WEB-INF/properties/messages in the form of key value pairs.

Now, let's say you want to inject the messageSource in a class called ClassA and you have a setter for it (setMessageSource). All you have to do is have the spring container manage that class as one of it's bean. That means you declare the class as a bean in your applicationContext.xml like so:

```
<!-- I am not setting the scope of this object as I don't know what it should be. You should do that based on your needs -->
<bean id="classA" class="com.somepath.ClassA">
</bean>
```

thats it! when the spring container initializes this class it will recognize that it has a field called messageSource of type ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource and inject the messageSource in the instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Bozho said after you declare `MessageSource` Spring will automatically detect the type and inject the properties file it finds at "WEB-INF/properties/messages[.properties]" that you just set up in your context, then you can use it like this `messageSource.getMessage("name"[,...])` or you can go the old-fashion way and your bean can implement `MessageSourceAware` and then you would need to include a public setter for `messageSource` -- you wouldn't need to **explicitly** inject the `messageSource` in this case either Spring would recognize the interface implemented and do the injection automatically for you.